# Ajax 403 on POST Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a jQuery image cropper. When an image is cropped and a button is pressed to send it to the file via ajax (as seen below) I get a 403 Forbidden error.

```
$('body').on("click", '.saveimage', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "save.php",
        data: foo.crop(200, 200, 'png')
    }).done(function(data) {
    });
});
```

I am not using the Django framework and I'm trying to look for answers but all I seem to find are Django or Tornado answers. This is save.php:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
    {
        $img = str_replace('data:image/'.$_POST['type'].';base64,', '', $_POST['string']);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

        // logic to determine file name
        $filename = 'smush';

        file_put_contents($filename . '.' . $_POST['type'], base64_decode($img));
    }
?>
```

No errors are being logged, I have not got any csrf implemented yet. All help is appreciated. If I'm missing something, let me know.

Comment: What value is the `crop()` function returning? To upload a file via AJAX you generally want to use `FormData`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to find out. The only way I know how to send this data is via ajax post request. I can print it to console or even generate a preview. the crop() function returns a base64 string and when put into a preview it shows the cropped image as it should. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Use `debugger` and Dev tools to find out what's happening? @cMk...

Comment: $.ajax() data property should be an object e.g {key: value} pair, in save.php you are getting type and string values from POST array but these values are not posting by ajax request, in order to get $_POST['type'] and $_POST['string'] values set data property an object like this data: {type: 'png', string: 'your string'}
I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie All components used are in the same folder.

Comment: @MasoodRehman Would having faulty data such as this cause a 403 error?

Comment: I'm not sure may be but one thing that i sure is the ajax data property is an object of key value pair, what are you posting in the $_POST['string']?